# checking if the character pointer has string literal or undeterministic value

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question on character pointers.

Lets say I have:

```
char * x = malloc(len);
```

The above does not return a NULL also.

Now depending on a condition:

```
if (<condition>)
  strncpy (x,y,len);
```

How can I check if `x` contains any string literals? 
Because then I need to do:

```
strncpy(z,x,len);
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please stop using c++ tag when you use malloc, strncpy and pure char pointers

Comment: What do you mean by `if x contains any string literals ?`

Comment: I think what he means is that to see if strncpy was successful i.e. was the string copy from y to x being successful

Answer (score 2):

> How can i check if `x` contains any string literals?

In general you can’t. C gives no guarantees about the addresses used here so you cannot reliably determine where they come from.

But you’re probably addressing the problem the wrong way round: why does this confusion about the origin of `x` exist in the first place? If you simply want to ensure that the value is always `malloc`’d, simply always `malloc` it instead of storing the direct address to a string literal.

(I find it generally odd that the target of your copying should depend on the origin of a value …)

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you want to check if the `strncpy` function returned successfully. And the answer is::

> strncpy does not returns any value to indicate an error

So, I think you have to `printf` the variable `x` to see exactly if it contains any string literals and `strncpy` was successful.

**EDIT::** 
Try this:

```
int isZero ;
char * x = malloc(len);
memset(x, 0, len) ;
if (<condition>)
    strncpy ( x, y, strlen(y) + 1);

isZero = strlen(x) ; /* if not 0, you know something is copied */
if( isZero != 0 )
    strncpy( z, x, (strlen(x) + 1) );
```

Comment: correct, but printing the variable is not quite a good way to check if strncpy was successful. Rather, one can use strlen to check the length of the string and see if it is equal to len

Comment: Yeah correct, though you can't check the strlen with len. strlen will return the length of string in x = length of string in y which can be != len (size you have malloced). You can however check with, if( strlen(y) == strlen(x) ){ //Do something }

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is a homework question. Anyways from the manual pages of malloc,

```
malloc() allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The memory is not cleared.  If size is 0, then malloc() returns either  NULL,  or  a  unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().
```

In most of the cases, when `malloc` fails `NULL` is returned so a check can be performed.

In your question, I'm comfortably assuming that `if x contains any string literals ?` means that you want to check if the `strncpy` was successful. `strncpy` by default returns a pointer to the destination. So, you will surely land up in a segmentation fault if malloc had returned NULL.

One simple way can be check if strlen of x is equal to len.

strncpy is quite a dirty function and your code is prone to lot of bugs !

man is the best friend for a novice programmer. I guess you should go through them and do a little more research before posting questions.